# Interval wont stop when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My interval wont stop, when i click my submit button, and then start the interval afterwards.

Im making a chat system, that's supposed to reload the chat over and over again, but the message submit is VERY slow when the chat reload is running, so its supposed to stop the chat reloading when the message submitting is running, and then start again afterwards.

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     function auto_load(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "index.php?url=userchat1&id=1",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $("#chatdiv").html(data);
          } 
        });
      }
      auto_load();
      //Refresh auto_load() function after 500 milliseconds
      var myVar = setInterval(function(){ auto_load() }, 500);

        $('#beskedform').on('submit', function (e) {      
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'index.php?url=chatsubmit&id=1',
                data: $('#beskedform').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $("#msg").attr('value','');
                    $("#msg").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("#msgbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
                    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ auto_load() }, 500);
                }
          });
          clearInterval(myVar);
          $("#msg").attr('disabled','disabled');
          $("#msgbutton").attr('disabled','disabled');  

        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
                        <form id="beskedform">
                            <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="form-control content-group" rows="3" cols="1" placeholder="Skriv din besked..."></textarea>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                    <button type="submit" id="msgbutton" class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-labeled-right"><b><i class="icon-circle-right2"></i></b> Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: `myVar` inside the success callback is shadowing the outer `myVar`. They are two different variables.

Comment: How do i fix thay?

Comment: @elclanrs tells the truth. Remove var keyword in success callback

Comment: But i want it to stop the interval when i click the button and then start it when the ajax has been submitted

Comment: Could it be that your AJAX is being executed before the `clearInterval` and DOM manipulation?  If so, you'd have two intervals running and you'd only be clearing the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use this script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 function auto_load(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "index.php?url=userchat1&id=1",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $("#chatdiv").html(data);
      } 
    });
  }
  auto_load();
  //Refresh auto_load() function after 500 milliseconds
  var myVar = setInterval(function(){ auto_load() }, 500);

    $('#beskedform').on('submit', function (e) {      
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'index.php?url=chatsubmit&id=1',
            data: $('#beskedform').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#msg").attr('value','');
                $("#msg").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#msgbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
                myVar = setInterval(function(){ auto_load() }, 500);
            }
      });
      clearInterval(myVar);
      $("#msg").attr('disabled','disabled');
      $("#msgbutton").attr('disabled','disabled');  

    });
});
```

Comment: It took me 3 minutes to find the change you made (before I read the comments above)... You should at least explain why you did it, that's what makes an answer _good_.

Comment: There is no difference between my script and the one you posted?

Comment: @TechTimeGames there is one difference, `myVar = setInterval(function(){ auto_load() }, 500);` we don't redefine `myVar`, but instead we use already created variable